# How to print PDF files automatically from a directory?

Tags: printing, pdf

Currently, I have a directory called MY-SHARED, and I need the following to happen:

1. Print all PDF files that I place into MY-SHARED
2. The printing must initiate automatically (no human interaction)
3. After printing, it should automatically delete the file

How can I accomplish such task?

As a side note, I'm novice in the Ubuntu world.

Comment: About point 4, notice that is practically impossible to be sure that the file has been printed. You can check it has been sent to the printer, but printed is quite more complex and really never fail-proof (and probably printer-dependent).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Install the package `inoticoming`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install inoticoming
   ```
2. Install the package `trash-cli` to use your trash folder instead of deleting the PDF

   ```
   sudo apt-get install trash-cli
   ```

   If you prefer the deletion of the file via the classical `rm`, than you don't need this package and you have to replace the line

   ```
   lpr "$2/$1" && trash "$2/$1"
   ```

   with

   ```
   lpr "$2/$1" && rm "$2/$1"
   ```

   in the script below.
3. Create wrapper script `printpdf`

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/bin
   gedit ~/bin/printpdf
   ```
4. Add the code below, save the file and close the editor

   ```bsh
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   FILE="$1"
   if [ "${FILE##*.}" = "pdf" ]
   then
       lpr "$2/$1" && trash "$2/$1"
   fi
   exit 0
   ```
5. Make the script executable

   ```
   chmod +x ~/bin/printpdf
   ```
6. Watch your folder

   ```
   inoticoming /path/to/MY-SHARED ~/bin/printpdf {} /path/to/MY-SHARED \;
   ```

---

And as [@Rmano](https://askubuntu.com/users/16395/rmano) said in the comments

> About point 4, notice that is practically impossible to be sure that the file has been printed. You can check it has been sent to the printer, but printed is quite more complex and really never fail-proof (and probably printer-dependent).

Comment: +1, even if you forgot to delete the file after printing (or at least moving in a trash, on the line of `lpr [...] && mv file trash`) ;-)

Comment: @Rmano Ups o_O =)

Comment: Great guys, now all my home computers can print to the Epson L200 printer installed on the station with Zorin 9.1. At home my dad has a notebook with Linux Canaima. And now I need not install drivers. Also happens to my mom using a Chromebook like mine, it's just print the PDF to said network folder and everything working. Thanks very much, I love you a world ;-*

Comment: If I have a problem I call to 0800 ASKUBUNTU GUYS! hehehe

Answer (score -1):

Thank you, [that](https://askubuntu.com/a/675198/618353) works like a charm. Especially if you put it as cronjob to activate `inoticoming`, it can even print all sort of pictures and PDF.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/bash
FILE="$1"

if [ "${FILE##*.}" = "jpg" ]
then
        lpr  "$2/$1" && rm "$2/$1"

elif [ "${FILE##*.}" = "jpeg" ]
then
        lpr  "$2/$1" && rm "$2/$1"

elif [ "${FILE##*.}" = "png" ]
then
        lpr  "$2/$1" && rm "$2/$1"

elif [ "${FILE##*.}" = "pdf" ]
then
        lpr  "$2/$1" && rm "$2/$1"

elif [ "${FILE##*.}" = "svg" ]
then
        lpr  "$2/$1" && rm "$2/$1"

else
 echo "finish"

fi

exit 0
```